# Can the record.save execute near simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, database, asynchronous, netsuite, suitescript2.0

The code is as follows:

```
function afterSubmit(context) {
         ...
    inv_record.save();
    po_record.save();
}
```

After the user submitted a PO record which would update the PO UNIT COST on Invoice as well, NetSuite seems to execute saving Invoice record first and then saving PO record.

Can the different records be saved synchronously without waiting the former record finish saving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [record.save.promise](https://560765-sb1.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4440842328.html), but it can only be used in *client-script*. On *server side*, NetSuite does not allow saving multiple records asynchronously.